# How to do a dynamic fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a RSS feed with a lot of news.
When I go to a news want to implement left and right swiping for next and previous news 
Here is my code for the fragment :

```
public MyFragment(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint({ "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "InflateParams" })
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inline_browser, null);
    ww = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.inlineBrowser);
    browserSettings = ww.getSettings();
    browserSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    browserSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browserSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    browserSettings.setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);

    browserSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    browserSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    browserSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

    ww.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    ww.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    ww.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ww.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    ww.loadUrl(url);
    return v;
}
```

}

And here is the code where I introduce to fragment transiction:

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inline_browser);
    feed = (RSSFeed) new WriteObjectFile(this).readObject(RSSUtil
            .getFeedName());
    position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");
    setTitle(feed.getItem(position).getTitle());
    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.inlineBrowser);
    url = feed.getItem(position).getURL();
    browser.requestFocusFromTouch();
    browser.setInitialScale(1);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment(url);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.browserFrame, fragment);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: use `ViewPager` to do this thing.

Answer (score 0):

A Fragment should have the public default constructor only (no args).
If not, Android won't be able to recreate this Fragment when necessary.

So, normally you would do:

```
public MyFrag() {}

public static MyFrag newInstance(String url) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("url", url);
    MyFrag f = new MyFrag();
    f.setArgumentd(b);
    return f;
}
```

Then you use `MyFrag.getArguments().getString("url")` whenever you need your passed url.